# parsing XML document Spring Config

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to read the spring configuration xml from the Unix file system but it throws this error, if I run it in windows this code works perfectly but when running in Unix does not load the xml.

Already validate that the xml exists in the unix file system and if it exists in the indicated path:

```
         private static final String URL_UNIX="/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml";


                String locate = "";
                locate= new File ("").getAbsolutePath ();
                String urlFinal= locate+URL_UNIX;               

                    System.out.println("*****" +"Loading Config Context from File Sistem :UNIX *****");

                    File fichero = new File(urlFinal);


                        //Validate that configuration file exists
                    if (fichero.exists()){
                        System.out.println("*****" +"if exis  file: True *****");

                        // value urlFinal= /home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml
                  ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(urlFinal);

                    }else{

                        logger.error("*****" +"ERROR: " + urlFinal +" NO Existe  *****");                       
                        exitCode = -1;
                        throw new Exception("*****" +"ERROR: " + urlFinal +" NO Existe  *****");

                    }
```

Stack Traced:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [/home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml (No such file or directory)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at fi.banamex.s440.business.reports.ReportRunner.main(ReportRunner.java:96)
    at fi.banamex.s440.business.reports.BatchDispatcher.main(BatchDispatcher.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 19 more
```

I'm using: Spring framework 3.2 and jdk 1.6

Comment: i would expect an initial slash before home/wasbin/...... as /home/wasbin/....

Comment: I think you're missing the / in home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml

Comment: Thanks, I see the value of urlFinal if it contains slash

IOException parsing XML document from file [/home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a prefix in the absolute path "**file**"

```
 // value urlFinal= "file:/home/wasbin/test/SCRIPTS/config/contextConfig.xml";

        ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(urlFinal);
```

Load Success!